# ListFragment with Custom Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, slider, android-listfragment, android-adapter

I have setup a `listfragment` in my project. but it seems my fragment cant get it right with my adapter. its because of `Context context` in `MyListAdapter`. if i click to correct it. it changes into `MenuFragment menuFragment`. But after that changes, `MyListAdapter` got error. so i correct it. it changes into `Context context`. and again if i correct it, its still goes on and on. its looping like that.

Note: What i want to achieve is ListFragment with icon. like my other question before (but unfortunately no one answer it).

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);  
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

     String [] proMenu ={ "Homies", "Best Nearby", "Coupon" , "Profile" , "History" , "", "Setting" ,
               "About" , "Sign Out"};

     setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, proMenu));

}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    Fragment newContent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        newContent = new ColorFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent intent7 = new Intent();
        intent7.setClass(getActivity(), Home.class);
        intent7.putExtra("index", position);
        startActivity(intent7);
        break;
```

EDIT : This is my layout. its perfectly fine now. i just have to tweak the textview and linear layout, so that the word not cut in half. but i'm facing another problem. its like the background image is piling up each other. this is the xml on my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
android:background="@drawable/menu_drawer">  

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/row_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: the layout]

And if i remove this `android:background="@drawable/menu_drawer"` from the `linear layout`. it will be the perfect background. not piling up each other. but when i'm swiping in the list, the background go nuts, its gone and showing some black background in it. its like the problem with listview `android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"`. i already added that `cachecolor` in `linear layout`. but its still showing those black background. its like this.

[image: this is what happen when i remove <code>android:background</code>]

i know whats the problem are. its because the default background are black. but i dont know how to solve it.

EDIT2 : Black Problem Solved.

SOLVED.

Comment: First of all, you use `android:layout_height="50dp"` for the row height so it's normal that the text will be cut as it can't fit that height(especially as you use a 20dp size(use sp instead)). Use `wrap_content` for the row height. Secondly, the `cacheColorHint` attribute needs to be used on the `ListView` and not the row background(you could set it in code).

Comment: thank you. you saved me a lot. actually i have 1 final question. how to make space between history and setting. so the 3 list will be in the botton (setting, about & sign out).

Comment: If that is some kind of menu, then you're better off by replacing the `ListView` with a `LinearLayout` which will contain the rows so you could spread them apart like you want.  You could still do it using the `ListView` by calculating the exact space needed for the screen and adding an extra empty row with that height.

Comment: thanks. i updated the question :D
actually its the menu. slidemenu from **jfeinstein10**

Comment: I said to insert a single empty row for which you calculate the proper height. You should really start a new question regarding this.

Comment: okay thanks. btw how to insert it ? programmatically? thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't pass a valid `Context` to your adapter, a `Fragment` **isn't** a `Context`. You need to use , for example, an `Activity` as the `Context`:

```
setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), proMenu));
```

I hope you also implement the `getCount()` method in the adapter otherwise you'll not see anything in the `ListView` no matter how many elements do you have.

Comment: many many thanks to you so many much thanks. finally after a week it SOLVED.

FYI = i didnt implement getCount() and it still work perfectly. but there is one problem though. my text didnt look so fit in the list. lets say when menu "nearby". the bottom of the word "y" didnt fill in the list. it just half. its like "u".

Comment: @Nicolas The text is cut off at the bottom? Can you post your layout file?

Answer (score 1):

```
Following is the method to create listFragement list view:
HealthAdvice.java

package com.example.babs;


import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class HealthAdvice extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.health_advice, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        HealthAdviceArray health_data[] = new HealthAdviceArray[]
                {
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Cloudy"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Showers"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Snow"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Storm"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Sunny")
                };

        HealthAdviceAdapter adapter = new HealthAdviceAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.health_advice_item_row, health_data);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the list view */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}// end main class HealthAdvice

Step 2:

HealthAdviceAdapter.java
package com.example.babs;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HealthAdviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HealthAdviceArray>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    HealthAdviceArray data[] = null;

    public HealthAdviceAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, HealthAdviceArray[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        HealthAdviceArrayHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new HealthAdviceArrayHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (HealthAdviceArrayHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        HealthAdviceArray weather = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(weather.icon);

        return row;
    }

    static class HealthAdviceArrayHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
    }
}

Step 3:

HealthAdviceArray.java

package com.example.babs;


public class HealthAdviceArray {

    public int icon;
    public String title;

    // we are over loading here
    public HealthAdviceArray(){
        super();
    }

    public HealthAdviceArray(int icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
    }

}

step 4: 

Health Advice health_advice.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

step 5:

Health Advice items: health_advice_item_row.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_view"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you creating your Custom Adapter don't pass "Context" object as reference just pass the Activity object to the Custom Adaper.

```
public class HealthAdvice extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.health_advice, container, false);

        return rootView;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        HealthAdviceArray health_data[] = new HealthAdviceArray[]
                {
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Cloudy"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Showers"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Snow"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Storm"),
                new HealthAdviceArray(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Sunny")
                };

        HealthAdviceAdapter adapter = new HealthAdviceAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.health_advice_item_row, health_data);

        /** Setting the array adapter to the list view */
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

}// end main class HealthAdvice
```